# What means tilde in windows file pattern

Tags: windows, winapi, glob, tilde-expansion, filepattern

I have pattern to search. Say "*.txt".

Now I have some files I do not want to list there. I believe they do not match this pattern.
But on windows, they do.

I know tilde character is used to make short form of legacy 8.3 filename. That is LongFilename.json might be LONGFI~1.JSO. But I did not know they are handled somehow on windows in file search patterns. They are. I cannot find any documentation about what they mean and how to match files my way.

My problem is NOT with short forms. Or I think it is not directly related to it.

I have file "A.txt". Now I wanted temporary file and used "A.txt~". It is unix backup files that is not usually visible. But on windows, they should not have special meaning by itself. Only for my application.

Now I want list of "*.txt" files. Command
        dir *.txt
returns to my surprise also all *.txt~ files in the same directory. And I do not want them. I use FindFileFirst from Win32 API. I did not find anything about tilde character in documentation. FindFileFirst("*.txt", handle) returns also files "A.txt~". Can I use some flag to exclude them? I know I can make special condition, like I have for "." and "..". How does ~ operator work? A.txt~1 is also matched. Is everything after tilde ignored? Is that feature or bug?

I am testing that on Windows 7 Professional, 64 edition, if that changes anything.

Comment: I've seen something like this too.  In my case, it wasn't with the tilde.  To use your example, I was searching for "*.txt", but it was matching as though I'd said "*.txt*".  Rename your file so the extension is ".txt1" and see if it still gets matched.  It might not be about the tilde, but about how that function performs a match.

Comment: Oh! You are right of course. I did not even consider it might be that way. It seems I am unable to match file ending with something, because there is implicit * at the end. A.txt1 really matches dir *.txt :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FindFirstFile` also includes short names for legacy reasons so the pattern `*.txt` will include anything with an `8.3` representation ending in `*.txt` which includes `*.txtANYTHING` , not just the `~` character (see `dir /x`for what's being matched against).

You will need to filter in your FindNext enumeration.

Comment: Yes, it seems so. It only applies to suffix of length 3. *.html does not match *.html1. But *.htm does match *.html and *.html1. Strange side effects of legacy files handling.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for .txt files for example, you can use "kind:text" option in windows to exclude txt~ and similar files since they are not a recognized type anymore.

That's something that works on regular windows search. I'm not 100% sure about the API, but it should also be there.

Comment: Problem is I use old Win32 in application, where I found problems with that. Where would I enter "kind:text"? I do not want to use File Explorer.

Comment: This is more like an SQL approach. This page might help. I'm not really the expert on the topic but this worths a shot I guess.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx